# Bitwise NOT in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a simple application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  unsigned int a = 0x2; //= 10b
  unsigned int b = ~a;  // should be 01b
  printf("%04x : %04x\n", a, b);
}
```

I wonder, why does it print `0002 : fffffffd` instead of `0002 : 0001`?

Comment: All the 0's that come before the 1 in 10 which represents 2 are also converted to 1's by doing ~

Comment: int's size is not 2 bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're right. However an unsigned integer is (usually) 32 bits long (on a 32 bit system).

So you're not only flipping the last two bits but the 30 bits before as well.

To solve this, you'll just have to mask the bits you're interested in:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int a = 0x2;       //= 10b
    unsigned int b = ~a & 0x3;  //= 01b (0x3 = 11b)
    printf("%04x : %04x\n", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
fffffffd(hex) -> 11111111111111111111111111111101(binary)
00000002(hex) -> 00000000000000000000000000000010(binary)
```

As you can see, they ARE bitwise negations of each other.

Answer (score 1):

`02x` is an integer constant. On a 32-bit system that corresponds to `0x00000002`, only with insignificant zeros omitted. When you invert that value, you get back `0xfffffffd` - precisely the value that you see.

If you want to keep only the last two bits, mask with `0x03`, like this:

```
unsigned int b = ~a & 0x03;  // will be 01b
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/FbjfAi)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `2` is represented in binary o(on 32 bit machine) as

```
00000000000000000000000000000010
```

and its bitwise NOT is

```
11111111111111111111111111111101
```

which is equivalent to `fffffffd` in hex.